# Is it possible for a beamer command to produce multiple sequential slides?

Tags: beamer

I often find myself writing equations in beamer where a calculation unfolds step-by-step.

For example, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \frametitle{Example}

  \begin{example}
    $
    \onslide<1->{a^2+b^2}
    \onslide<2->{=}
    \onslide<3->{c^2}
    $
  \end{example}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to be able to write a command to produce this equation. Something like this gets me started:

```
\newcommand<>{\Pythagoras}{
  \onslide#1{a^2+b^2}
  \onslide???{=}
  \onslide???{c^2}
}
```

I'd like to be able to issue `\Pythagoras<n->` and have the equation start unveiling itself on the `n`th slide. Since each slide of the equation is in sequential order, I thought that maybe there is something I could replace `???` with.

Is this possible?

Comment: Let me ask you a silly question. How did you create that GIF? I may assume you did it very quickly because you created a question on-the-run. I'll really appreciate your answer

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar In linux I used the command `convert -density 600 -delay 100 foo.pdf foo.gif`. It works really well!

Comment: Amazing. The `convert` command is like a Swiss army knife and I was using just the knife. Cheers pal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I interpret the question correctly, but this seems to fit:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\def\Pythagoras<#1>{\onslide<\the\numexpr#1-2\relax->{a^2+b^2}
    \onslide<\the\numexpr#1-1\relax->{=}
    \onslide<#1->{c^2}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \frametitle{Example}

  \begin{example}
    $\Pythagoras<4>
    $
  \end{example}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```